# Segments of a hypotenuse

Tags: geometry

The hypotenuse of a right triangle is divided into 2 segments by the altitude to the hypotenuse
The sum of the greater segments on the hypotenuse of 2 disimilar right triangles is equal to the perimeter of a 3 4 5 right triangle.
The 2 disimilar triangles contain the same altitude to hypotenuse as the 3 4 5 triangle, and one angle equal to one half the 2 acute angles in the 3 4 5 triangle..

What are the 2 disimilar triangles and the greater segments on their hypotenuse?

Hint: one acute angle and the altitude to the Hyp of the 3 4 5 triangle is enough information to find both disimilar right triangles & determine all 3 sides of each one.

Comment: A good picture would make the question a lot more digestible and would increase the chances of someone answering it.

Comment: How do you add pictures?

Comment: The perpendicular to the hypotenuse divides the triangle into to triangles both similar to the original triangle.

Comment: @Bob In the area where you enter your question, the 6th icon from the left looks like a mountain inside a frame. Click on that. :)

Comment: @wltrup As far as I can recall, adding picture icon will be “awarded” only if one’s score is 100 or more. I don’t know whether there is a change in such rule or not.

Comment: @Mick oh... didn't know that.

Comment: Marty Cohen, the question is not about the triangles similar to the original triangle. It deals with 2 disimilar right triangles, created, using the altitude to the Hyp of the 3 4 5 triangle, and one acute angle equal to 1/2 the acute angles in the 3 4 5 triangle.

Answer (score 0):

The disimilar right triangle with one acute angle equal to 1/2  the lesser acute angle in the 3, 4, 5 triangle, and the same altitude (2.40), to the hypotenuse as the 3, 4, 5 triangle, has the hypotenuse at 8.00. The segments on the hypotenuse are 7.20 and 0.80.

The disimilar right triangle with one acute angle equal to 1/2 the greater acute acute angle in the 3, 4, 5 triangle, and the same altitude to the hypotenuse as the 3, 4, 5 triangle, has the hypotenuse at 6.00. The segments on the hypotenuse are 4.80 and 1.20.

7.20 + 4.80 = 12.00 the perimeter of the 3, 4, 5 right triangle.